# Use Group by in sql

Tags: sql

I have a precipitation_full table and has following schema

```
    station_id
    day
    precipitation
```

Now I want to get `station_id`'s which have average precipitations > 75 with group by. I used this code in jupyter but my result is incorrect:

```
select station_id 
from precipitation_full 
group by station_id  
having avg(precipitation) > 75
```

How I Can do this with Group by and nested query?

Comment: `jupyter` has nothing to do with this. I deleted the tag.

Comment: Describe what "my result is incorrect" means.  What did you get?  Why is it wrong?  What did you expect?

Comment: @BaconBits I just give one station_id But Answer has many station_id

Comment: Could you provide sample data and expected output. This would solve a lot of questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM precipitation_full 
WHERE station_id IN (
        SELECT station_id 
        FROM precipitation_full 
        GROUP BY station_id  
        HAVING AVG(precipitation) > 75
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT station_id, AVG(precipitation)
FROM precipitation_full
GROUP BY station_id
HAVING AVG(precipitation)>75
```

Answer (score 1):

[James5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47579965/1094048)' answer looks right. But if you want all rows (not just unique station_ids), use this:

```
;with _intermediate as (
    select
        *,
        avg(precipitation) over (partition by station_id) as AveragePrecipitation
    from precipitation_full
)
select
    station_id,
    [day],
    precipitation
from _intermediate
where
    AveragePrecipitation > 75
```

In my answer I assume you use `Sql Server`.